# Upserting with mongodb's java api

Tags: java, mongodb

I have tried to work with some examples but I cannot seem to figure out how to upsert in mongodb with Java while it is dead easy to do it in other languages (namely python).

I have the following code (note createDBObject just puts a bunch of fields into a dictionary, see print below):

```
    public static void mongo_test(HashMap<String,String> arg){
        DBObject opt = createDBObject(arg);

        try{
            if(Double.valueOf(arg.get("Bid"))>0.0){


                //should be upsert
                WriteResult res = col.update(opt,null,true,false);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

Where `System.out.println(opt)` gives me:

```
{ "date" : 20150601 , "ticker" : "SPY" , "callPut" : "C" , "Last" : 18.95 , "Vol" : 6.0 , "Chg" : 0.0 , "maturity" : 20150605 , "Symbol" : "SVXY150605C00070000" , "Open Int" : 6.0 , "Strike" : 70.0 , "Ask" : 20.6 , "Bid" : 17.9}
```

And I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: update can not be null
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.update(DBCollectionImpl.java:244)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:214)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:247)
    at yahooscrape.yahooScrape.mongo_test(yahooScrape.java:283)
    at yahooscrape.yahooScrape.main(yahooScrape.java:216)
```

Now, the error message is quite clear, but what exactly is the proper solution for me?

I have tried a couple avenues and this seemed most correct but also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on the method:

`collection.update(DBObject q, DBObject o, boolean upsert, boolean multi)`

Acc to mongoDB Java API:

> Parameters:
>
> - q - the selection criteria for the update
> - o - the modifications to apply
> - upsert - when true, inserts a document if no document matches the update query criteria
> - multi - when true, updates all documents in the collection that match the update query criteria, otherwise only updates one

- You don't have any specific selection criteria. So, you can add empty `new BasicDBObject()`as a selection criteria for selecting everything.
- `opt` is the modified object
- need to set `upsert` `true`
- you want to update only one doc. So, `multi` is `false`

You need to update your code with:

```
WriteResult res = col.update(new BasicDBObject(),opt,true,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

MongodB java update is follows

```
 collection.update(DBObject q, DBObject o, boolean upsert, boolean multi).
```

you are providing the **arg** as query not update,so this may be correct

```
col.update(createDBObject(new HashMap<String,String>()),opt,true,false);
```